# How to zoom video camera in iOS7 on iPhone4(S)

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, avfoundation, avcapturedevice

As part of an app I’m developing a video camera. The camera has zoom functionality.
I use the AVCaptureDevice’s activeFormat to determine the maximum zoom factor:

```
AVCaptureDevice *device = […];
AVCaptureDeviceFormat *format = device.activeFormat;
CGFloat maxZoomFactor = format.videoMaxZoomFactor;
```

This works fine on an iPhone 5 or newer. But on iPhone 4S or older, the maxZoomFactor is always 1, i.e. it doesn’t support zooming.

I thought maybe the AVCaptureDevice’s activeFormat was not the desired/right format, but iterating over all available formats for the device showed that there is no format that supports zoom.

```
NSArray *formats = device.formats;
for(AVCaptureDeviceFormat *format in formats){
        if(format.mediaType == AVMediaTypeVideo){
          CGFloat maxZoomFactor = format.videoMaxZoomFactor; //on iPhone 4S maxZoomFactor is always 1
       }
}
```

I’ve seen other apps zoom video on iOS7 on an iPhone4S (although the default camera won’t let you either), so there has to be another way. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: check this : http://pastie.org/8984963

Comment: Thanks @Mayur, I had a look at that code. Am I right that the zoom is implemented with the pinch gesture? And that all the pinch gesture does is apply a scale transform to the preview view, i.e. it's not actually changing the video output?

Comment: See my answer here. I hope it will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799110/apply-cgaffinetransform-prior-to-layer-being-displayed/22834443#22834443